# PDF getting created with permission 600?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, jasperserver, permission-denied

I'm experimenting a weird issue. Most of the time (almost everytime) my pdf are getting generated with the permission (rwx-r--r--) 644 which is correct.

But 'sometimes'.. and I cannot understand why this happens but they get created with permission (rw-------) 600. this cause a "permission denied" when other systems try to copy or read the PDF...

Did someone already had this issue? Is it possible that is it a problem in my Jasper config ? or the Server config ?

Ps: I'm running my web app on an redhat server (container is Weblogic ).

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the program through which you run and generate PDF is in the same permission that is root.

you can run your PDF generating software ( or whatever you are using ) in home user mode and not root user mode)

Or just go to that folder where your PDF has been generated and run from terminal

```
user@your_folder>> sudo chown username:username *
```

give password if asked.... You can use this with every file and folder that has this problem

You will see once you run this command a 'LOCK' icon goes away and file/folder becomes normal

Hope this helps you